# WordPress ou Site feito sem CMS?

Tags: html, wordpress, cms

Queria saber ser é melhor fazer um site para WordPress ou fazer ele sem CMS, pois estou criando um site de notícias sobre tecnologia e etc. Se é mais fácil usar o WordPress ou o site comum sem CMS.

Comment: Com html5  e css3

Comment: É pq vi muita gente comentando que o WordPress é muito bom de se trabalhar.

Comment: Então não adiantaria muito se dissessem que é melhor com WP né? É meio complicado esse tipo de pergunta; depende muito do que vc vai fazer. Pense comigo: se fosse bom só de um jeito, todo mundo faria só de um jeito. Na verdade depende do que você vai fazer, depende do que você pretende com o site, de quem vai usar, quem vai manter, que tipo de conteúdo tem, onde vai hospedar, etc. Seria legal você dar uma especificada no caso prático que vai precisar, para ter como sair uma resposta objetiva. Da forma como está, além de muito ampla, só vai atrair resposta opinativa, que não ajuda ninguem.

Comment: @Bacco melhorei a pergunta ?

Comment: Acho que quase nada kkk. Bom, só dei um toque pra você entender os possíveis problemas dela, vamos ver a reação da comunidade. Se tiver um tempinho, dê uma espiada em [Ask], tem umas dicas lá também.

Comment: Kkkkk é que não sou muito bom com explicaçõws.

Comment: Eu não gosto de usar o WordPress para desenvolver sites, mas admito que poderia usá-lo. Pelo  que eu vejo os programadores fazendo aqui, a melhor opção em quase todos os casos é usá-lo. E personalizar o mínimo possível. Digo isto porque muitos dos problemas que as pessoas postam aqui poderiam ser tratadas pelo WP facilmente. A pessoa não tem um problema novo, algo que exija um programação nova. E as pessoas mostram que não conseguem fazer coisas bem básicas, então é melhor ela não fazer, pega algo pronto. Programação é para cosia nova e para quem sabe o que está fazendo.

Comment: Sim. Eu usaria WP, agiliza muito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                                    USANDO CMS WordPress
```

O WordPress em si é uma ferramenta que com certeza vai facilitar por parte, pois como é uma aplicação pronta ele já lhe da diversas opções para que possa fazer um site bonito utilizando os Plugins e temas. O problema do WordPress é que como se trata de uma aplicação pronta, é preciso ter cuidado, pois a performance dele é inferior a de um site criado manualmente, devido a funções que muitas vezes não precisamos, e ao colocar em uma hospedagem com servidor compartilhado, pode ocorrer lentidões e dores de cabeças com instabilidades de ficar dando "RESOURCE LIMIT", ou seja, recursos limitados, e também existe o problema de está sempre atento com novas atualizações, pois como é um dos CMS mais utilizado, é muito visado pelos hackers, pois tem como você escanear todo o conteúdo, e ver se existe algum plugin, tema e a própria base desatualizada, ai que os hackers fazem a festa.

```
                                   CRIANDO MANUALMENTE
```

Criando um site manualmente, você pode definir o que vai ser realmente utilizado pelo processamento do servidor, pois ali você tem um maior controle sobre a aplicação, porém ainda existem os riscos, isso se for utilizar PHP, pois existem os tais "sql INJECTION", que consegue entrar dentro do banco através de ferramentas e conseguir os dados sem problemas, o cuidado tem que existir sempre, porém fica mais fácil manter seguro quando se sabe o que está colocando, além da performance muito superior.